# Uso de print en python. Línea horizontal

Tags: python

Cómo pinto 5 `U`s en horizontal y otras 4 líneas debajo, formando un cuadrado de 5x5

Con 2 bucles anidados

```
for y in range(5) y for x in range(5)
```

pinta todo en vertical.

con esa instrucción: `print('A', end=' ')`, pinto un cuadrado de 5x5 `A`s, si no pongo `end=' '` pinta 5 columnas verticales de As, supongo que el secreto está en `end=' '`, es así?.

Sin `print()` final pinta las `A`s en vertical.

Quiero que la diagonal, en vez de ser `A`s sean `D`s, las posiciones `(1,1), (2,2)...(5,5)`, supongo que se hará con algo así:

```
if x=y print 'D'
```

Gracias

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento.

Comment: `if x=y print 'D'` es no es Python.

Comment: Eso es Python 2.7 o qué?

Answer (score 1):

Creo que quieres algo parecido a esto:

```python
for i in range(5):
    for i in range(5):
        print('·', end='  ')
    print()
```

La instrucción 'print' tiene el parámetro opcional 'end' que define cómo deseas que termine la impresión. Por defecto es un salto de línea pero puedes poner cualquier cosa que se pueda imprimir, siempre que sea una cadena de texto (no vale 5, pero sí vale '5'. También vale la cadena vacía '', que juntaría un print con el siguiente).
En el ejemplo anterior hay dos espacios para que salga más cuadrado el dibujo de los puntos.
Puedes consultar todas sus opciones aquí:
https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#print

En ciertos casos es muy útil el tabulador: end='\t'

Para conseguir la diagonal debes controlar que la posición en la fila sea la misma que la posición en la columna con un código parecido a este:

```python
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        if i == j:
            print(0, end='  ')
        else:
            print('·', end = '  ')
    print()
```

Disculpen los fallos de edición, es la primera respuesta que hago en esta gran comunidad que me ha solucionado tantas dudas.

Comment: Efectivamente, con esa instrucción: print('A', end=' '), pinto un cuadrado de 5x5 As, si no pongo end=' ' pinta 5 columnas verticales de As, supongo que el secreto está en end=' ', es así?, sin print() final pinta las As en vertical
Quiero que la diagonal, en vez de ser As sean Ds, las posiciones (1,1), (2,2)...(5,5), supongo que se hará con algo así: if x=y print 'D'
Voy a probarlo. Gracias

Comment: Hola toniet, gracias por publicar una respuesta. Por favor, edítala para añadir algo más de detalle: ¿qué es lo que cambiaste con respecto al código de la pregunta? ¿Cómo soluciona ese cambio el problema? Lee [answer] para más información.

Answer (score 1):

El método print(), tiene un parámetro que se llama "end", y por defecto su valor es '\n', que es un cambio de línea. Por eso cuando usas print 2 veces seguidas, el segundo print se imprime debajo del primero. Para que no haga ese cambio de línea, tienes que añadirle ese parámetro "end" para modificarlo, por ejemplo:

```
print('primero')
print('segundo', end = 'sin cambio de línea') 
print('tercero')
```

Dará como resultado

```
primero
segundosin cambio de líneatercero
```

Como ves, ahora "tercero", sale escrito a la derecha de "segundo", con el valor de "end" entre los dos.

Por lo que necesitas algo como:

```
for y in range(5):
    for x in range(5):
        print('A', end = '') # string vacío
    print() # Cambio de línea
```

Que daría como resultado:

```
AAAAA
AAAAA
AAAAA
AAAAA
AAAAA
```

El parámetro "end" tiene un string vacío para evitar el salto de línea, pero dependiendo del resultado que quieras puedes introducir lo que consideres.

Ahora, para hacer una diagonal de Ds, lo más sencillo que se me ocurre, es poner en el bucle interior (el que contiene el print('A', end='')), añadir un if tal que:

```
for y in range(5):
    for x in range(5):
        if x == y:
            print('D', end = '')
            continue
        print('A', end = '') # string vacío
    print() # Cambio de línea
```

Lo que hacemos aquí, es que cuando la coordenada x, sea igual que la coordenada y, se imprime una D, y llegamos a la palabra clave "continue". Esta palabra, lo que hace es dar paso al ciclo siguiente del bucle, por lo que, cuando se imprima una D, no se imprimirá una A. Lo que da como resultado:

```
DAAAA
ADAAA
AADAA
AAADA
AAAAD
```

Answer (score 0):

con lo siguiente consigo hacer lo que quiero, un cuadrado de 5x5 `A`s con la diagonal formada por `D`s

```
for y in range(5):
    for x in range(5):
        #print('·', end='  ')
        #print('A',)#pinta 5 columnas verticales de 5 As
        #print('A', end=' ')#pinta 5x5 As
        #if int(y) = = int(x) then:
        if y==x:
            print('D', end=' ')
        #else
         #   print('A', end=' ')
        if y != x:
            print('A', end=' ')
    print()
```